# Selenium framework using C# and excel

Tags: selenium, test-automation-framework, c#, excel

I am new to automation (Selenium ). I am working as manual tester and recently got a task related to selenium automation.

I have basic knowledge of selenium and very good knowledge of C#. I can create a simple test in Selenium like login, check mail, send mail etc., but all this is in one page and has no input from excel.

I need a framework that takes input from and compares expected results with excel data. I can change example code according to my needs.

Comment: It sounds like you are using excel to manage test cases and expected results.  Have you looked at frameworks like specflow to manage your tests?  That way everything is managed in the code and you don't have to load from external files

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: yes i am using visual studio express version 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an Excel library to load data from Excel files and use that data in your Asserts?

- C# and Excel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657131/how-to-read-data-of-an-excel-file-using-c
- C# and Asserts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have already wrote a code to read and write in excel file , I am asking for some sample selenium framework.

Comment: There is not known framework that does this. I think its up-to your self to write some classes that combine Selenium and Excel as you wish, this should not be to hard. Also I do not think many people combine Excel and Selenium as it is unhandy to separate test-step-data from the tests, since it makes them harder to read in code.